# Startup orientation when device orientation locked

Tags: android

In my app I use setRequestedOrientation() with *SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR*, or with *SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR* when *System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION* indicates disabled rotation. I think that's how Im supposed to do this but the app behaves differently on different devices. I got:

1. One where app orientation is always the same as that of home screen, locked or not
2. One that is forced to vertical orientation when rotation is locked, other than that the same as #1
3. One that behaves like #1 until the app is stopped, then it is always started in vertical orientation even if device itself is locked to landscape

#3 is what people complain about. Apparently they expect the "lock" to keep everything at the same orientation, whilst according to docs *System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION* is not supposed to lock anything but only disable accelerometer detection. Looks like some vendors interpret this differently though.

Is behaviour #3 a normal thing, or is it a specific device bug that I should work around somehow? How do I get locked orientation or orientation of the home screen? Is it at all safe to mess with orientation when it is locked?

Edit:
The app decides whether it would be appropriate to allow switching between landscape and portrait depending on the device (screen aspect ratio and few other things). Neither setting one fixed orientation through manifest, or allowing the system to handle rotation was an option in this case. Going to accept my own answer now to have this question closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Using *SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR* when accelerometer rotation is enabled and *SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER* when it isn't, works as expected on all devices I've tested so far.

NOSENSOR seemed like a fitting option at first, but looking at the docs now, it only says that accelerometer will be ignored and nothing about what orientation it resolves to, I guess it really is indeterminable. Kind of useless option and a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

### you can set your  default Orientation through manifest

Comment: android:screenOrientation="screenOrientation you want "

Answer (score 0):

Force your orientation statically in manifest for each activity. For example if you want to force "portrait" orientation for an activity, add this attribute into your activity tag in manifest file:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: It would be very easy to force particular orientation. What I would prefer is to make app behave the way users expect it to when they lock orientation, that is to always appear in the orientation they chose to lock their devices to. As long as this can be achieved safely, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do anything.

If the user has disabled device rotation, and you're not trying to force a specific orientation, your app will load in their chosen orientation.

You don't need to explicitly set `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` or `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR`.

When you disable rotation on the device, it will lock the preferred orientation to what it is currently in. Some launchers (home screens) don't support landscape, so even if the device is supposed to be locked to landscape, they will still display in portrait. When launching an app that doesn't lock the orientation, it will change back to landscape